# Responsive site – Layout issues when resizing the browser to a small width and then back to a large width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I’m making my first full responsive site and I have run into an issue. The site seems to be working as intended in firefox and explorer. The browsers that are giving me issues are chrome and safari.

On the bio/landing page (http://designerdsite.com/new/) toward the bottom of the page are two sections one titled “I Got Skills”, the other titled “and they love me for them”. When I load the page (no matter what size the browser width is) it loads correctly however after the browser width is shrunk and then reopened the layout repositions. In the “skills” section the div on the right side is falling below the div on the left. In the setion “they love me” the text is falling below the pictures. It seems for some reason the width on the container div is not being understood. Perhaps its something else. I am really not sure what is going on here and would very much appreciate any advice anyone has. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a similiar issue on my site. As far as I could figure this out, it seems that Chrome/ Webkit has a problem with the correct (re-)positioning of floated elements.

So there are 2 (maybe more) options:
1. You may use Javascript to force the Browser to re-render (not reload!!!) these elements (e.g. by changing the display property to none and back to block)
2. Use another positioning variant like 'inline-block' or 'table-cell'

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) that will make your life really easy.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you used `media-query` for your site right???...anyway so iguess you know the reason....for example lets assume your last `media-query max width` was defined as `600px` ...then it will work fine upto 600px and below(not far)....when your browser is resized to `width:480px (for ex.)` then your design like font-size,padding etc are getting very large to fit two divs side by side....so if you want to keep your design intact for microscopic width then lets have one more media query definig that limit `max-width:480px;`

for example

```
.fonts{
   font-size:18px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    .fonts{
        font-size:10px;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with all the percentage widths. I know WebKit can have issues with nested and rounded percentages etc, so when the page is resized both the widths on the images and quotes, as well as padding on the parent element are recalculated.

You'll see if you remove the `padding: 0 5%` on the `max-width` class, the problem no longer occurs.

Try wrapping the quotes in a 100% width div:

```
<div class="quote-wrapper" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="reference clear-both">
        <img src="images/monica.jpg" alt="Monica" class="reference-pic">
    </div>
    <div class="quote">
        <p><em>“Paul is the most committed hard working person I've had the pleasure to supervise. If he was unfamiliar with something he did the research to inform himself and others. Paul is one of those rare breed of people who comes to a supervisor with options not just problems.”</em></p>
        <p>Monica Luchak, Former Director of Creative Services, BoardSource</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much. I was really frustrated! You rule man!! Thank you everybody for your suggestions!

Comment: @PaulWilcox That's great Paul, glad you got it sorted. If you don't need any more help, could you mark the answer accepted? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how browsers compute percentages. A quick fix for that is to set a `max-width` for the left container:

```
#skills-left {
  float: right;
  width: 47%;
  max-width:411px;
}
```